# SQL joining on multiple conditions where ranking may be required

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem

I have two tables that I need to join under multiple conditions. For the most part this is simple except for the last condition:

```
Select * from tableA
left outer join tableB on condition1
                        OR condtion2
                        OR condtion3
                        OR condtion4
                        OR <the record with the most recent tableB.date before tableA.date that has not already been joined in the above conditions>
```

I have tried a few options such as using cross path, a nested query and case statement to no avail. (always seems to be gettting a 1:M match, or incorrect match)

Is there any way I can ensure that there is only a 1:1 mapping (ie if the record from table B is already mapped to a record in tableA via a previous condition then to not match it on the last condition?)

Example:

TableA: (decisions)

```
ID
-----
DEC1
DEC2
DEC3a
DECX
```

TableB: (tasks)

```
ID    
-----
TASK1
TASK2
TASk3
TASK4
```

expected out:

```
DecID|TaskID  
------------  
DEC1 |TASK1
DEC2 |TASk2
DEC3a|TASK3
DECX |TASK4
```

the first 3 rows are covered by existing conditions. but the DECX could map to any task that is not already mapped

Comment: can you show some sample data and what you expect as the result instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tableA
left outer join tableB 
  on condition1
  OR condtion2
  OR condtion3
  OR condtion4
UNION
Select * from tableA
left outer join tableB 
  on <the record with the most recent tableB.date before tableA.date that has not already been joined in the above conditions>
  AND NOT condition1
  AND NOT condition2
  AND NOT condition3
  AND NOT condition4
```